# How to print content type template with document information panel?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, printing, document-info-panel

I created an Excel template for a custom content type in SharePoint 2013 and then I created a custom document information panel (DIP) using InfoPath 2013. When I add a new file to my document library of that content type, Excel 2013 opens correctly and displays the DIP form. I can edit the file and the DIP, save it and the new document appears in the document library. However if I then open that item the DIP is not visible. The values in the DIP are available in the Info tab of Excel after clicking on "Show All Properties". However I would like to be able to print and/or view the document with the panel showing as it did when I first created the document. Is there any way to make this happen?